# getting file from S3 bucket in pyspark generates enc version error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I can't figure our why this code generates the following error.

"Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require    AWS Signature Version 4"

I've tried setting boto_config to use sigv4 and that didn't work either.

```
import os
import boto
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession


def main():
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] =\
        '  --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.199,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.9.0 pyspark-shell'

    conf = (SparkConf()
            .setAppName("s3a_test")
            .set("spark.executor.instances", "8")
            .set("spark.executor.cores", 2)
            .set("spark.shuffle.compress", "true")
            .set("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
            .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g"))
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "myAccessKeyId")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "mySecretAccessKey")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.endpoint", "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
    df = sc.textFile("s3://s3-bucket/xyz/myfile.csv")
    print(df.count())


    sc.stop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: And where is the error? :)

Comment: The error is as shown above "Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4"

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm not getting a specific error, but I'm getting an Access Denied and I'm wondering if this is part of the issue.